Noun or adjectival clause

It was in this land that the Rasool was born, in the city of Makkah, which is about fifty miles from the Red Sea.

In the above mentioned sentence 'that the Rasool was born' seems noun clause that is following a noun 'the land' that should be followed by an adjective clause or phrase which is coming later in the same sentence like  'in the city of Makkah, which is about fifty miles from the Red Sea.' Is it grammatically correct sentence if not then what would be its correct order?

It's perfectly grammatical. The first clause, which could have been written The Rasool was born in this land, has been inverted for stylistic effect. Presumably the previous sentence told us something about 'this land', and this sentence adds some more information about it. Compare:

At the head of The Mall stands Buckingham Palace. It is this palace that contains the administrative centre of the British monarchy.


Consider:

The book was placed on the blue shelf.
-- Why was it placed on a shelf for glue?
Sorry, you misheard me. It was on the blue shelf that the book was placed.

This form of the sentence, where so-called "expletive" or "dummy" It is the subject, is a way of making a fact or piece of information salient.
The salient information in my example is "on the blue shelf". The salient information in your example is "in this land".

OP's query concerns the two dependent clauses in the sentence:

It was in this land that the Rasool was born, in the city of Makkah, which is about fifty miles from the Red Sea.

Both dependent clauses,  "that the Rasool was born" and "which is about fifty miles from the Red Sea," function as adjective clauses.     However, they both ultimately describe "the city of Makkah" rather than "the land."
To simplify the sentence and remove redundancy, we can eliminate  "It was in this land," resulting in:
The city of Makkah, where the Rasool was born, is about fifty miles  from the Red Sea.
